# Gallery design with hr after every four items

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I need to design a gallery as show in the image below. So far i have completed it but i am facing design issue.

I need to show four items in a container of width 800 pixels with each div padding on right and bottom plus border-bottom:1px.

[image]

Assuming page 4 has only one Item then it shows up as. i am not sure how to  design it in such a way so that i can have line after every four elements & if the last page has 1,2,3 
items then the line should be across the whole width not just under that item. The way i have it i don't think it is possible. I am not sure how to add a horizontal line after every 4th item.

I am doing this in asp.net using repeater control.

I would appreciate a pointer.

My code

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptVideoGallery" runat="server" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="video-wrapper">
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hylnkvideo" CssClass="youtube"  NavigateUrl='<%# getURL(Eval("VID"), Eval("YoutubeID")) %>' runat="server">
                                <div class="video-image-wrapper">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgvideo" ImageUrl='<%# getImagePath(Eval("thumbnail"), Eval("YoutubeID")) %>'   AlternateText='<%# getTitle(Eval("Title")) %>'  runat="server" CssClass="vthumbnail" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="playVideo">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgPlay" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/playVideo.png" BorderWidth="0" />
                                </div>
                               <div class="video-title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" CssClass="vname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" CssClass="vdate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                               </div>

                            </asp:HyperLink>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

**Update**: Other idea i have to add hr tag after every 4th item & remove boder from all items...

Answer (score 1):

I can propose css-solution using :nth-child selector in order to find the 1st item of each line and to place hr above it:

```
.video-wrapper li:nth-child(4n+1):after {
    content: "";
    width: 760px;        /* fixed width of container without paddings */
    height: 1px;         /* height of border */
    background: #555;    /* color of border */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But each item should have the same height this way. Oh, and it seems like old browsers won't understand these css selectors . Here is complete version - http://jsfiddle.net/caprella/Srrjj/.

Comment: I would love to use this approch only problem is that it is not supported by IE 8 7 below... if i am not wrong

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use ItemCreated event handler to remove bottom border from last 4 items and then just add one hr or div below all items

```
int currentItem = 0;

    //This value will be set when data source retreives data
    int totalCount = 43;

    protected void Repeater1_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        currentItem++;

        //This will give you last 4 items 
        if (currentItem > totalCount / 4 * 4)
        { 
            //remove bottom border using inline css 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your specific issue, but you might also consider just putting the 4 images into a div, then putting a border-bottom on it, except the last div.

The HR tag has very vague semantics and is therefore considered to be a mostly presentational tag. Since modern designers tend to abhor presentational HTML tags, they tend to stray from this.

Also due to vague semantics, browser treatment of HR varies wildly. You have some control over its styling, but not much, and it's not consistent.

Using divs instead, if you can, is less moving parts, more semantically concise (in that you're not implying anything with divs), and easier to create and maintain.

Comment: I solved this issue using jquery by adding hr tag after 4th div as i only need to display 8 image and bottom row has no border.